# Error con librería xlrd: no such file or directory error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Actualmente tengo este código y funciona perfectamente cuando corro la aplicación en Windows(server de desarrollo)

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\carga\pacientes.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Cuando subo la app a Ubuntu y ejecuto la aplicación desde Windows aparece este Error:

```
no such file o directory "C:\\carga\\pacientes.xlsx"
```

Agradecería alguna sugerencia?

Comment: si te fijas windows y linux ubuntu tienen diferentes rutas... ubuntu no puede acceder o no tiene esa ruta... c:....

Comment: Gracias @DiegoAvila eso significa que debo subir el archivo al servidor Ubuntu?

Comment: en efecto... porque la app busca el archivo en dicha ruta... entonces tu app debes cambiar la ruta de c:-.... a la nueva ruta en linux